# PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() in CLI on Ubuntu server

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

PHP MySQL on my Ubuntu server works fine in Apache, but not in CLI

This happened after a botched upgrade attempt from 5.3 to 5.6 (the upgrade didn't replace 5.3 but installed 5.6 alongside. php -v shows 5.6, but phpinfo shows 5.3!)

I get the error PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_query()

I have tried many steps: symlinking the apache's config to the cli directory so they match, making sure mysql module is listed in phpinfo which it is, adding extension=mysql.so or extension=php_mysql.so or extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626/mysql.so (and all directories that have mysql.so in), none of which work.

I don't know where to go from here.
Yes I know I should use mysqli but I haven't got time right now to recode hundreds of pages to use mysqli.

UPDATE: I changed one file to mysqli and even that isn't working in CLI: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried restarting apache after that?

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed this now, as the CLI PHP version was 5.6, upon installing php-mysql I had to specify the version apt-get install php5.6-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to use mysqli_query instead of mysql_query

> mysql_connect will be replaced by mysqli_connect mysql_query will be
>   replaced by mysqli_query($con, $query)

Comment: I don't have to, as I said it works fine in Apache and CLI was working fine before installing 5.6 alongside the 5.3

Comment: then do one thing. Install sudo apt-get install php5-mysql

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15346605/php-apache-php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysql-connect

Comment: Is your PHP -v really 5.6 ?

Comment: PHP 5.6.9 (cli) (built: Jul 13 2016 01:56:29)

Comment: Apache phpinfo = PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.23

Comment: I changed one file to mysqli and now even that isn't working Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed this now - see above